# How to remove part of a sentence based on the frequency of a particular letter in using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is a URL I scraped to google Sheets from the internet. I want to delete an original part of it. There I found a pattern like this. The symbol `"/"` is used several times in every URL. I want to remove the characters up to the fourth occurrence of `"/"`.

The URL inside the cell is like this `https://www.wensite.com/username/how-to-remove-part-of`
The result should be like this.  `how-to-remove-part-of`

Since the URL is wrapped, remove it and copy the link using the code below.

```
function urlText(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lC = ss.getLastColumn();

  for(i=2; i<lC; i++){
  var cellVal = ss.getRange(2,i).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();

  var count = cellVal.length;
  var find =cellVal.lastIndexOf("/");
  var remove =cellVal.replace().endsWith(find);
  
  //ss.getRange(9,i).setValue(cellVal);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your answer of `I solved the problem using this code`, when I saw it, I'm worried that `getRange`, `getRichTextValue()` and `setValue` are used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. So, as another approach, I would like to propose the following modification by reducing the process cost.

#### Modified script:

```js
function urlText() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1);
  var values = range.getRichTextValues()[0].map(c => {
    var url = c.getLinkUrl();
    return url ? (url.split("/")[4] || null) : null; // or return url ? url.split("/").pop() : null;
  });
  range.offset(7, 0).setValues([values]);
}
```

- I think that when this script is run, the same result as the script in your answer is obtained.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRichTextValues())
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I didn't know exactly how to use the `map()` function. Thanks for informing me. I will learn it.
Here, the `range.offset(7, 0).setValues([values]);` section brings everything together in one cell. To set a cell range, you have to use a `for loop`, right?

Comment: @TipVisor Thank you for replying. About `Here, the range.offset(7, 0).setValues([values]); section brings everything together in one cell. To set a cell range, you have to use a for loop, right?`, in this part, from `ss.getRange(9,i).` in your script, the range is down 7 rows by keeping the column length with `offset(7, 0)`. And the values are an array retrieved from the URLs retrieved from `sheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1)`. So, I think that in this case, it is required to use the for-loop. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @TipVisor About `map()`, I think that [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) might be useful.

Comment: thank you for your support. I have another question. how to calculate process cost in the code?

Comment: @TipVisor Thank you for replying. About your new question of `I have another question. how to calculate process cost in the code?`, I think that this might be useful. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-google-apps-script#benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this code

```
function urlText(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lC = ss.getLastColumn();

  for(i=2; i<lC+1; i++){
  var cellVal = ss.getRange(2,i).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();

  var count = cellVal.length;
  var find =cellVal.lastIndexOf("/");
  var remove =cellVal.slice(find+1,count);
  
  ss.getRange(9,i).setValue(remove);

   Logger.log(remove);

  }
}
```